# Twig not looking in project's app/Resources/views folder for template

Tags: php, twig, symfony-3.4, knpmenubundle

I am working on an upgrade from `Symfony 2.7` to `Symfony 3.4`.

When trying to load twig template from controller, it is not searching in project's `app/Resources/views/` folder.

This is my controller's code:

```
return $this->render('::layout.html.twig', [
    'user' => $this->getUser()->toArray(),
    'token' => $this->get('st_api.token_repository')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser(), 'isSystem' => true]),
]);
```

This is the error I get.

```
Unable to find template "::layout.html.twig" (looked into: 

/var/www/website/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views,
/var/www/website/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).
```

I don't understand why it is not looking into the project's app/Resources/views/ folder. Also, I don't know why it looks into the knp library at all?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please do ask in case any more information is required.

Comment: Look up bundles inheritance and twig templates extentions

Comment: The controller from which I am trying to access the template is `MainController`. It is under `CoreBundle` which extends `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle`. So, I don't find any bundle inheritance.

Comment: Also, I checked in all the custom twig template extensions in the codebase. There are no signs of knp there.